# Can the Efficiency of this Algorithm be Linear?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

My textbook says that the following algorithm has an efficiency of O(n):

```
list = [5,8,4,5]

def check_for_duplicates(list):
    dups = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] not in dups:
            dups.append(list[i])
        else:
            return True

    return False
```

But why? I ask because the `in` operation has an efficiency of O(n) as well (according to [this resource](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/Lists.html)). If we take `list` as an example the program needs to iterate 4 times over the list. But with each iteration, `dups` keeps growing faster. So for the first iteration over `list`, `dups` does not have any elements, but for the second iteration it has one element, for the third two elements and for the fourth three elements. Wouldn't that make 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 extra iterations for the `in` operation on top of the `list` iterations? But if this is true then wouldn't this alter the efficiency significantly, as the sum of the extra iterations grows faster with every iteration?

Comment: Is your text book specifically using Python, or is this your implementation? If you use a `set` instead of a `list` for `dups`, then the lookups will be O(1), and the total running time will be O(n).

Comment: ok, thanks i got it - it was using JS and using a slightly different implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the runtime of the code that you've posted here is O(n<sup>2</sup>), not O(n), for precisely the reason that you've indicated.

Conceptually, the algorithm you're implementing goes like this:

- Maintain a collection of all the items seen so far.
- For each item in the list:

  - If that item is in the collection, report a duplicate exists.
  - Otherwise, add it to the collection.
- Report that there are no duplicates.

The reason the code you've posted here is slow is because the cost of checking whether a duplicate exists is O(n) when using a list to track the items seen so far. In fact, if you're using a list of the existing elements, what you're doing is essentially equivalent to just checking the previous elements of the array to see if any of them are equal!

You can speed this up by switching your implementation so that you use a `set` to track prior elements rather than a list. Sets have (expected) O(1) lookups and insertions, so this will make your code run in (expected) O(1) time.